# Count the number of times a combination of two values occurs in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to count the number of time a combination of two values occurs in a cell. For example:

```
ADD UINTRAFREQNCELL:RNCID=1,CELLID=3,NCELLRNCID=1,NCELLID=2;
ADD UINTRAFREQNCELL:RNCID=1,CELLID=3,NCELLRNCID=1,NCELLID=4;
ADD UINTERFREQNCELL:RNCID=1,CELLID=1,NCELLRNCID=1,NCELLID=1;
```

What I'm trying to archive is:
=> count the number of times the combination of `UINTRAFREQNCELL`/`UINTERFREQNCELL` and the value of `CELLID` occurs:

So for the first two lines, the value will be `2` and for the third line the value will be `1`.

How can I archive this?

Comment: Could you share some sample data with us & the expected result will help us to fix the issue.

Comment: 3 values you show is values of 3 separate cells in a column?

Comment: @Akina yes they are three separate columns

Comment: And the value 2 for first two cells is calculated because they contain 'UINTRAFREQNCELL' substring and 'CELLID=3' substring? And the cell value has this format always, or there exists a lot of formats? in last case show some variants (maybe all if their count is small).

Comment: @Akina Correct. All of the cells contain either 'UINTRAFREQNCELL' or 'UINTERFREQNCELL' and  'CELLID=x'.

Comment: @aab, you mean to say that you want to count if cells are filled with `UINTRAFREQNCELL` and `UINTERFREQNCELL` and `CELLID=x` ?  Otherwise no if any one is missing!!

Comment: *contain either 'UINTRAFREQNCELL' or 'UINTERFREQNCELL' and 'CELLID=x'* So if we change 1st cell to `ADD UINTERFREQNCELL:RNCID=1,CELLID=3,NCELLRNCID=1,NCELLID=2;` the result will be the same?

Comment: And you want to do it: by one formula only, by formula(s) plus additional column(s), by user-defined function?

Comment: @Akina the cell contains 'UINTRAFREQNCELL' and 'CELLID=x' OR 'UINTERFREQNCELL' and 'CELLID=x'; I want to count them separately. So if you change the first cell to ADD UINTERFREQNCELL:RNCID=1,CELLID=3,NCELLRNCID=1,NCELLID=2; the result will be different.

Comment: Well... The substring `CELLID=x` is always delimited by comma (`CELLID=x,`), or it can be delimited by comma or semicolon (`CELLID=x,` or `CELLID=x;`), or some another delimiters (space or cell-end, for example) are possible?

Comment: Now I see the solution which uses one additional column.

Comment: @Akina it is always delimited by a comma.

Comment: If so, you can in additional column: extract `x` from `CELLID=x`, concat some char to it dependent by `UINTRAFREQNCELL` or `UINTERFREQNCELL` is present (for example, `A` or `E`), and use COUNTIF() by this column.

Comment: @Akina I've actually got it work using that method. However, I would like to use a single column for the calculation. Is that possible?

Comment: I cannot find the way to do it by single formula without user-defined function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `COUNTIFS` and wildcard characters:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"*"&"UINTRAFREQNCELL"&"*",A:A,"*"&",CELLID="&"*")

=COUNTIFS(A:A,"*"&"UINTERFREQNCELL"&"*",A:A,"*"&",CELLID="&"*")
```

Here's a sample (I've bolded the relevant terms manually):

[image]